# Can I configure exim to deliver new mail to Maildir cur/ instead of new/?

Tags: exim

I would like to set up an Exim4 delivery driver or perhaps a .forward/filter file that delivers certain mail straight to a MailDir's "cur" dir, instead of the "new" directory.

Is this possible?

Background/reason/idea: I am trying to implement a way for certain emails to avoid being "pushed". This way unimportant (as determined by a filter rule, e.g. from a list) emails can get delivered to an inbox without the staff member getting a push notification. I believe that files in the cur/ directory will only arrive on a normal poll, and not be picked up by typical push implementations.

Comment: I can't see why a .forward file, or a sieve filter couldn't do that sort of thing.

Comment: To complete the sieve part have a look at what `setflag "\\seen";` can do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can implement rules in sieve, which both Courier and Dovecot support, you can create a rule using the `Seen` flag, which is how a message is flagged after it is moved from the new to the cur directory.

Comment: Ah yep. Looks possible if I: reconfigure Exim to deliver local stuff to Dovecot LDA; configure dovecot for sieve; provide the sieve file for dovecot. Might leave this one a while, Exim's manual is excellent but Dovecot's is ... um ... not up to the same standard!

Comment: The info is out there, it just requires more digging to find it :) The dovecot mailing list is really good though.

Comment: Ok, got LTMP installed, configured, got exim to deliver via that, installed sieve and got that working (with virtual users), and implemented your solution. Unfortunately it's not what I was looking for: it marks it unread. I need to see that I have not read it, but don't want it to trigger a push notification. I tried `\Recent` but that's not settable from sieve. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: That is tough (I assume you mean it gets marked read though), I think the problem is sieve scripts shouldn't interfere with the function of the IMAP server, where what you want to do is actually a "violation" of roles. According to djb, all that's being done is a rename new/filename to cur/filename (with optional info and flags), and if you didn't set the Seen flag, it would remain unread. I can't see any way to implement that in sieve though, you might have to do it with something external.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I meant 'read'. It's the sort of thing I could achieve if I had stuff filed into different folders, then monitor certain important ones of those on a push basis. Problem is, people want to just check one inbox, not several. Thanks for your help. I was thinking it might be something easy, turns out I was very wrong!