# exim4 maildir - make message read

Tags: debian, exim

I'm trying to setup exim4 to handle spam-suspected messages moving them to the Junk user folder. So, I made a router:

```
  spam_junk:
    debug_print = "R: local_user spam/junk moving to junk for $local_part@$domain"
    driver = accept
    domains = +local_domains
    check_local_user
    local_parts = ! root
    condition = ${if def:header_X-Spam-Status:{YES}}
    transport = mail_spam_junk
```

and transport:

```
mail_spam_junk:
  debug_print = "T: spam/junk delivery for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = appendfile
  directory = /var/spool/mail/$domain/$local_part/.Junk/
  create_directory
  directory_mode = 0770
  mode_fail_narrower = false
  message_prefix =
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  maildir_format
  user = mail
  group = mail
  mode = 0600
  message_suffix = S
```

But this does not work. I'm not too familiar with the maildir format, but as I understand, the problem is, that MTA puts all new messages in the 'new' folder. Also, I don't see any 'S' (tried ',S' as well) in the resulting file name.

Anyway, the question is, how to make such a messages marked as 'read'? Thank you

Comment: I don't think the it's the MTAs job to manipulate maildir states.

Comment: @grin I think it is )

Comment: It's not my job to fix human brain activity. ;-) People seem to use Sieve for what you want, and it's not in the MTA, surprise.
https://serverfault.com/questions/550610/can-i-configure-exim-to-deliver-new-mail-to-maildir-cur-instead-of-new

Comment: @grin yes, I already know there’s people without brains at all, don’t try to prove that so hard ))))

Comment: I see. Apart from *ad hominem* attacks did you find the link useful?

Comment: Sure you do )))) apart from posting meaningless personal comments, did you read the question and links you shared? ))))